# Patch Method Not Updating The Changed Field on File

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa, crud

I am trying to update the fields of a very large entity with the patch method. I want to update only certain fields instead of updating the whole file. Even if the request I sent returns as 200, the field on the file does not change.

My Controller:

```
@PatchMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<MyFile> updateFile(@PathVariable("id") Long id, @RequestBody MyFile updateMyFile) {
        MyFile updatedFile = myFileService.updateFields(id, updateMyFile);
        if (updatedFile == null) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok(updatedFile);
    }
```

My Service:

```
@Transactional
    public MyFile updateFields(Long id, MyFile updatedMyFile) {
        MyFile existingFile = getFile(id);
        if (existingFile == null) {
            return null;
        }
        updateFields(existingFile, updatedMyFile);
        var exp =  super.save(existingFile);
        return exp;
    }
    private void updateFields(MyFile existingFile, MyFile updatedMyFile) {
        Field[] fields = updatedFile.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (Field field : fields) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            try {
                Object updatedValue = field.get(updatedFile);
                if (updatedValue != null) {
                    field.set(existingFile, updatedValue);
                }
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

My save method:

```
@Transactional
    public ENTITY save(ENTITY entity) {
        entity.setEditedBy(getCurrentUserId());
        entity.setCreationDate(new Date());
        verifySave(entity);
        entity = persist(entity);
        afterSave(entity);
        return entity;
    }
```

No matter how hard I try, when I send a sample field, it updates it within the method, but it does not save to the file.

Comment: Sounds like you already did some debugging: You've figured out that the `updateFields(MyFile, MyFile)` method does its job correctly. The next step is to figure out what happens next. My guess would be it has to do with passing the updated file to `super.save`.

Comment: Why are you calling persist if the entity already exists? What does the verifySave/afterSave methods do? What is in your entity within the save call?